# When cast NaN to int, why does the value change depending on whether it is assigned to a variable or not?

Tags: c#

Casting double.NaN to int will be 0.

```
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)double.NaN));    // 0
```

**However, assigning double.NaN to a variable and then casting to int will be  -2147483648.**

```
double value = double.NaN;
Console.WriteLine (unchecked ((int) value));    // -2147483648
Console.WriteLine ((int) value);                // -2147483648
```

Why does the result change depending on whether or not assign it to a variable?

### C# Specification

6.2.1 Explicit numeric conversions

- In a checked context, the conversion proceeds as follows:

  - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, a System.OverflowException is thrown.
  - Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
  - Otherwise, a System.OverflowException is thrown.
- In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.

  - **If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.**
  - Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
  - Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.

### Envrionment

- Compiler: Visual Studio 2013
- Rimtime: .NET Framework 4.6.0
- OS: Windows 10 Version 1607
- CPU: Intel Core i7 920

Windows:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion);    // Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);      // 4.0.30319.42000
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine (unchecked (int) double.NaN);    // 0` -- This line doesn't compile.

Comment: I suggest you have a look in the IL - I suspect the *compiler* is performing the first conversion, and just hard-coding the result to 0. Whereas in your variable case you're asking the CLR to do it.

Comment: What of double.NaN isn't actually a double and thus converted twice in the second example? (I don't know why though)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)double.NaN));` prints `-2147483648` when I try it.

Comment: @Quantic Sorry, fixing it. I did not have enough brackets.

Comment: Have a look yourself https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? I don't get `0` either.

Comment: This reminds me of the countless "why does `int *c; printf("%d", *c);` print 37` undefined behavior questions that people ask about C. The specification tells you it will be some unspecified number. You shouldn't even be surprised if it's a different number every time you run the program.

Comment: You are in the realm of [Nasal Deamons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), it returns two different numbers because it "felt like it".

Comment: @DaveShaw Compiled with visual studio 2013

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I like the way you think!

Comment: The result of a runtime cast from a double to int is -2147483648 if the double is NaN in practice (all instructions that implement that conversion give that result), if it happens any other way (eg a constant-folded conversion) it might be something else

Answer (score 3):

By default a console app is compiled as `unchecked`. Thatswhy your last example shows the same value as the examples explicitly using `unchecked`.

For the rest of your examples, the specification section you quoted applies:

> - In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
>   - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an **unspecified value** of the destination type.

(emphasizing by me).

**Unspecified** means that you cannot rely on the result. It can be `0` or `-2147483648` or anything else.

I'd like to figure out what happens under the hood in your special case, but I get `-2147483648` for both ways. So it's hard to track down.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my system either but changing the .NET Fiddle compiler to ".NET 4.5" instead of "Roslyn 1.0.0-rc1" it shows up as zero: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ckfngN

Answer (score 1):

After looking around a bit, I think I get what's happening here.  You're not casting 0, you're casting NaN.  `int`, or `Int32` has a much smaller range than `double`.  I *think* these delightfully not-so-clear rules are working together to cause the difference:

> - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.
>     Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value.
> - If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.

The destination type here is the smaller `int`, and the value "-2147483648" that you're getting is the minimum value of a 32-bit signed integer.  This suggests that the casting operation is converting the NaN to [`double.NegativeInfinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.negativeinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to perform an operation with it. The nearest integer to `double.NegativeInfinity` is `int.MinValue`, which is the value you're getting.

All of that said, the fact that this value is **unspecified** means that the result you get can depend on too many factors, right down to whether or not you assigned a variable or even what processor architecture you have. You're not supposed to use NaN casting to do anything meaningful, so NaN is never assigned an actual set value (largely because then it would, by definition, be a number). For most purposes, a NaN result should be treated as an error for this reason. The actual value is, in the end, meaningless.