# Vector2.Normalize(EndPosition - StartPosition) is NaN What can I do?

Tags: c#, xna

Sometimes the two vectors EndPosition and StartPosition have exactly the same values in my application. In this case, Vector2.Normalize(EndPosition - StartPosition) is NaN and my application freezes afterwards because I use the variable direction later in my code.

What can I do if the two vectors EndPosition and StartPosition have exactly the same values? How can I check if direction is NaN? I just want to execute the next code block(after direction = Vector2.Normalize(EndPosition - StartPosition);) if the variable direction is not NaN.

For example:

```
  float distance;
  Vector2 direction;
  Vector2 StartPosition = new Vector2(400, 250);
  Vector2 EndPosition = new Vector2(400, 250);

  distance = Vector2.Distance(StartPosition, EndPosition);
  direction = Vector2.Normalize(EndPosition - StartPosition);
  // code where I use direction to calculate
```

Comment: Just check the magnitude of the vector (or distance). If its 0, you are in trouble. Its probably more correct to define a minimum threshold, and not 0. A magnitude of 0.0000000001 probably means something is about to crash and burn if you keep going as if its a non zero vector.

Comment: Thanx. This works for me. if (distance <= 0.0000000001f) //don't continue, else continue with calculating direction = Vector2.Normalize(EndPosition - StartPosition);

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an answer to this question (credit to InBetween and Toby60) and offer some tips:

Any operation involving `NaN` values returns `NaN`. When a `Vector2` is passed to `spriteBatch.Draw` containing a `NaN` the call does not draw anything to the screen, more specifically, it is drawn at the location `Int32.MinValue` see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536954/when-cast-nan-to-int-why-does-the-value-change-depending-on-whether-it-is-assig) for more information.

Use distance squared or Manhattan Distance whenever possible. The square root function (called in `Vector2.Distance()` or *Vector2*`.Length()`) is an order of magnitude slower than multiplying the other side by itself and testing against that value.

Removing the square root is not possible when normalizing a `Vector2`, but you can calculate the length of the vector first, and use that value to eliminate the second square root call, as well as two function calls.

Subtract the two `Vector`s first and store that value. This technique removes the need for a separate subtraction of the same values later, and provides a way to implement a logarithmic (starts fast and slows down as it approaches) movement pattern:

```
velocity = direction * .25f; // each Update it moves a quarter of the 
//distance to the target `EndPosition`
```

Here is the code as given with the above modifications.

```
float distance;
Vector2 direction;
Vector2 StartPosition = new Vector2(400, 250);
Vector2 EndPosition = new Vector2(400, 250);

direction = EndPosition - StartPosition;  // subtract first 
distance = direction.Length();

if(distance > 0.000001f) // compare to small non-zero value
   direction /= distance; // by definition of Normalize(), eliminates the second square root
else
   direction = Vector2.Zero;

// code where I use direction to calculate
```

The following code adds a speed and renames `StartPosition` to `Position`, and adds a `Velocity` and eliminates the "shake" once it has arrived.

```
// class level variables
float distance;
float speed = 4;
Vector2 direction;
Vector2 Velocity;
Vector2 Position;
Vector2 EndPosition = new Vector2(400, 250);

// inside of the Update method

direction = EndPosition - Position;  // subtract first 
if (direction.LengthSquared > .00001f) //eliminates the rest of the code if this quick check fails 
{
   distance = direction.Length();

   if(distance > 0.000001f) // compare to small non-zero value
      direction /= distance; // by definition of Normalize(), eliminates the second square root
   else
      direction = Vector2.Zero;
   Velocity = direction;
   if (distance > speed)
      Position += Velocity * speed;
   else
      Position += direction * .5f; // we do not want position flip-flopping around EndPosition, so move speed /2 and then speed /4 ...
}
else
{
   direction = Vector2.Zero; 
   Velocity =  Vector2.Zero;
}// just in case direction or Velocity is needed later, otherwise remove the else up to this line
```